# タスク管理アプリのビューが表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

当方プログラミング初心者かつ初投稿につき、読みづらい点あるかと思いますがご容赦ください。
現在、現場Railsにて、タスク管理アプリを作成中です。
タスク新規登録機能を作成し、タスクの詳細を表示するところでエラーが出てしまったので、解決法を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします

以下エラーメッセージ
[image: ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in TasksController#show]

該当のソースコード(app/views/tasks/show.html.slim)

```
h1 タスクの詳細

.nav.justify-content-end
 = link_to '一覧', tasks_path, class: 'nav-link'
table.table.table-hover
 tbody
  tr
   th= Task.human_attribute_name(:id)
   td= @task.id
  tr
   th= Task.human_attribute_name(:name)
   td= @task.name
  tr
   th= Task.human_attribute_name(:description)
   td= simple_format(h(@task.description)), {}, sanitize: false, wrapper_tag: "div"
  tr
   th= Task.human_attribute_name(:created_at)
   td= @task.created_at
  tr
   th= Task.human_attribute_name(:updated_at)
   td= @task.updated_at
```

コントローラ(app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb)

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    task = Task.new(task_params)
    task.save!
    redirect_to tasks_url, notice: "タスク「#{task.name}」を登録しました"
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

ディレクトリは以下の通りです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/231367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SyntaxErrorといっているので、構文エラーですね。
`,` や `(`, `)`, `do`, `end`が過不足ある、位置がおかしい、というときにSyntaxErrorになりやすいです。
(もちろんそれ以外にもいろんなケースでSyntaxErrorが起きることはあります。)

今回は、

```
simple_format(h(@task.description)), {}, sanitize: false, wrapper_tag: "div"
```

ではなく

```
simple_format(h(@task.description), {}, sanitize: false, wrapper_tag: "div")
```

でどうでしょうか？
`)`の位置が変わっていて、 `h(@task.description)`だけでなく、 `{}, sanitize: false, wrapper_tag: "div"`も `simple_format`の引数として扱うように変更しています。

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format
`simple_format`のドキュメントです

Comment: エラーに対しての回答だけでなく、ご親切にエラーの意味、リンクまで貼ってくださりありがとうございます。
無事に解決できました！